# Unable to get PATH to be set for all users

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi

Trying to get OpenJDK 17 installed for Pufferpanel. User pi can do `java -version` fine however Pufferpanel gets `bash: java: command not found`

My `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d/java.sh` have these lines:

```
#JAVA
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1+12"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

In addition `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1+12"` is set in `/etc/environment`

Full permissions have been given for `java.sh` and the `JAVA_HOME` folder with `chmod 777`. The user `pufferpanel` now can run the script however the error stays the same: `bash: java: command not found`.

Trying some things out and found this:

```
pufferpanel@raspberrypi:/home/pi$ whereis java
java: /usr/share/java
```

Meanwhile pi gives this output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ whereis java
java: /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1+12/bin/java
```

Good news is that Java does run as the user `pufferpanel`:

```
pufferpanel@raspberrypi:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1+12/bin$ ./java -version
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.1+12 (build 17.0.1+12)
OpenJDK Server VM Temurin-17.0.1+12 (build 17.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

My guess is that PATH is getting overwritten somewhere, just don't know where.

If there are easier ways to install Java that is higher than version 16 just to get Minecraft to work, please tell me!

Comment: "easier ways to install Java" - easier than what way? `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk` - I guess that's what you did, it should properly setup PATH and symbolic links and everything that's needed.. Your profile file looks fine.

Comment: @MirekPluta Apt sadly can't locate that. As far as I know, that only allows me to install openjdk 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the PATH in `~/.bashrc` worked out, copied `java.sh` and pasted it in. Couldn't find `~/.bashrc` at first, but [this helped to figure that out.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127056/where-is-bashrc)

As Pufferpanel is a different matter, I'm marking this the answer to my question which was getting Java to work as an user.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is fine, but you should probably create a custom.sh shell script in `/etc/profile.d/`

As for environment variables, like `JAVA_HOME`, they should go in `/etc/environment`

Comment: I've made an .sh script in `/etc/profile.d/`, however that did not work either. `JAVA_HOME` is set as well in /etc/environment. I'll update the question to add that information

Comment: Make sure group and other have permissions to the .sh script with `chmod 0644` to that file.

Comment: Didn't work. Threw the hat in the bag and tried `chmod 777` on the script and the folder Java is in (with -R). Rebooted and still `java: command not found` despite executing the script in `/etc/profile.d`